# Server/Nas server/???

Tags: server, nas

I'm looking for an operating system to put on a second hand web server I have just bought, I am wanting primarily to use the server as a humongous Nas with raid facilities to avoid loosing all my mp3 ect, I believe it's raid 5??mirroring?? Redundant??   I also want to play about abit with remote desktop ect but have no experience with Linux or ubuntu. Is there a version that would suit an amateur to accomplish all of the above and someone who wishes to learn, and play with remote desktop??  I pick Android stuff quite quickly, are there any similarities?? Thanks in advance. Dan

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be best off with http://www.freenas.org/ it will give you the easiest access and configuration.